# How to perform bitwise operations on 16bit numbers (Arduino)

Tags: c++, c, arduino, bit-manipulation

I'm working on an Arduino powered Tetris game. To keep track of the pieces that have fallen and become fixed I have an array of bytes

```
byte theGrid[] = {   
B00000000,
B00000000,  
B00000000,
B00000000,
B00000000,
...
```

This works great when the well is only 8 LEDs wide, but I need it to be 16 wide. Is there a way to perform bitwise operations on a 16 bit number, like a short? I tried just declaring theGrid as a short, but I'm getting this error no matter what I do.

```
tetris:62: error: 'B0000000000000000' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...leading 'B' only works with 8 bit values (0 to 255)...

from http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/IntegerConstants

Just use hexadecimal notation, ie. `0x0000` for 2 bytes.
`0x` signals that it is hex, and every digit (`0123456789ABCDEF`) replaces 4 bit.

Instead of bitRead and bitSet, you can use following code;
The variable is x and the bit number i, with i=0 is the right-most bit, 1 the next ...):

```
//set bit to 1
x |= 1<<i;
//set bit to 0
x &= ~(1<<i);
//check if bit is set
if(x & (1<<i))
```

Eg. `x &= ~(1<<3);` sets a value B11111111 (in binary representation) to B11110111,
that is 0xff to 0xf7. Btw., `x &= ~(1<<3);` is equivalent to `x &= ~8;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I was using byte is so I could use bitread and bitset. 

So if an L piece comes down and lands, I can bitset the appropriate bits like this 

    `bitSet(theGrid[pixelY], 15-pixelX);` and end up with

    `B1000000000000000,

    B1110000000000000`

Comment: @ddickson1 That can be replaced with C-style shifts and masks. I´ll add it to my answer...

Comment: Thank you, do you have a documentation page for that code, so I can understand what I'm doing better?

Comment: Just read your edit, that does make sense now. Thank you so much, I think this will do it!

Comment: Arduino has http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BitMask and http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/Bitshift, but there better explanations out there. It´s not Arduino-specific, but general C and C++. If only I could find some explanation why it works currently without writing it myself :/

Comment: You probably don't want to look through 500 lines of code you didn't write, but if that happens to be what you're into, I'm having trouble implementing your solution. Can you identify any obvious issues in my code?

http://pastebin.com/SEZM6Qiv

Comment: @ddickson1 What´s the problem? Compiler errors, wrong results, crash...?

Comment: It was just outputting garbage, but I noticed I used ampersand instead of pipe. Fixed it and now I have a totally different problem. Thank you very much. Your solution worked :)

Comment: In case you were wondering, here's the progress after your help!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ncUO6iISww&list=UUr4QgULvzT3W4j6Wx_KCdVA